# Update column after select

Tags: sql, select, procedure

I have a MS SQL stored procedure (SP):

```
SELECT *  
FROM tblA  
WHERE stateID = 1  
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

Still within the same SP, how do I update the stateID column for each row the SELECT statement returns?  The SP still returns the rows from the SELECT statement.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `UPDATE tblA SET something = something WHERE stateID = 1`?

Comment: Say the SELECT returns 5 rows, and for each row, I'd like to update its stateID to 2.

Comment: Why do you need the `SELECT` if you actually want to update the rows?

Comment: This is to manage the download items and if I have multiple downloaders, I don't want downloaders to get the same items.  I think by change the state to something else, there should only be 1 downloader that processes unique download items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique identifier within the results that are returned you could do this.

```
UPDATE tblA SET stateID = 2 WHERE download_id in (select download_id from FROM tblA  
WHERE stateID = 1  
ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this , because this will return same rows

```
update tblA
set col = value  
WHERE stateID = 1
```